# SVC-CODEPOINT error loading triples to MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, triples, marklogic-10

When trying to load an ntriples file with about 7M triples in it, I get the following error from the REST-API:

```
{"errorResponse":{"statusCode":500, "status":"Internal Server Error", 
"messageCode":"INTERNAL ERROR", 
"message":"SVC-CODEPOINT: (err:FOCH0001) xdmp:nquad($body, $options) -- Codepoint not legal . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail."}}
```

The error log is not more helpful here:

```
2021-01-13 14:24:53.771 Info: Status 500: SVC-CODEPOINT: (err:FOCH0001) xdmp:nquad($body, $options) -- Codepoint not legal
```

I have run the file through rapper and Jena's riot validation and neither tool kicks up a problem with the file, or any specific triples.

How might I troubleshoot this with MarkLogic?

I can generate a file that employs a different serialization, but that has me rewriting my code when this has worked in the past and works on two other files in the batch. And a different serialization might work or, if it doesn't, may generate the same error. In either case, I've not actually identified the issue.  There must be something in the file, but I'd like to find it because we also happen to be the source of the ntriples.

Comment: hmm, it would seem that somewhere there is a conversion or parse error. Before resorting to a binary search and processing chunks of the file - what about removing any characters that are alpha-numeric and seeing what is left? Maybe that will reveal the characters that it might be choking on? Or try putting the content inside of an XML structure inside of a CDATA block: `<doc><![CDATA[ PUT_NTRIPLES_CONTENT_HERE ]]></doc>` and then try parsing as an XML file to see if you get better diagnostics?

Comment: err:FOCH0001, Codepoint not valid.
Raised by fn:codepoints-to-string if the input contains an integer that is not the codepoint of a valid XML character. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#ERRFOCH0001

Answer (score 2):

I could delete the question, but if it helps someone...

Convert the ntriples to RDF/XML and load that file.  MarkLogic will spit out a more valuable error message:

```
2021-01-13 16:10:43.292 Info: Status 400: XDMP-DOCXMLCHAR: xdmp:get-request-body("xml") -- 
Invalid XML character codepoint 55358 at  line 14398744 -- document contains non-XML character
```

Comment: Curious, was it in the end a true bad character, or just something MarkLogic didn't like?

Comment: It was a true bad character (technically two), or an invalid unicode character to be precise.  I think it was generated by a non-MarkLogic utility when the RDF was exported.  MarkLogic had no issues once I replaced the two bad unicode characters with the correct one - https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html#1f929.  I shall reserve comment about emojis in RDF except to say it is legal.